# how to keep the volume at a specific level in Win7

Tags: windows-7, audio

So there are office pranks going on. I've been re-mapping windows sounds on my co-worker for hilarity, but now, a week later he decided he can just mute the computer. Is there a way to keep the volume at a non-zero non-max level, to thwart his muting?

Comment: That's just obnoxious.

Comment: Yes, it is. He's currently listening to various star wars sounds, but I'm trying to pull together enough audio from Bruce or the giant bee on Family Guy to cover the majority of sounds. But yes, obnoxious is the goal.

Answer (score 0):

Did you even TRY to google?

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-pictures/how-can-i-control-speakers-volume-using-command/e975aa3a-a956-e011-8dfc-68b599b31bf5

tl;dr No, there's no native way to command the speaker's volume.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Links in answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. Also, keep in constructive.

Comment: Yes, I did Google my question before coming here. I did not see anything like your link; obviously we used different phrasing. While I thank you for providing me with somewhere to continue looking, I would ask that you try not to use emphasis meant to be condescending. It doesn't reflect well on the rest of Stack Exchange or its users. I will mark this as the answer if this will work for me.

Comment: `It doesn't reflect well on the rest of Stack Exchange or its users`. @Andrew, neither does the lack of professionalism your question poses!

Comment: @Dave, the lack of professionalism that I present is not as off-putting as coming to a site dedicated to on-topic, informative, and civil QA
, and finding the same condescending attitude that I would expect from YouTube comments. To keep on topic, the above will not work. It links through to a nirsoft program where you can change the volume, but it does not stop the user from changing the volume while keeping it at a nonzero level.